Whats a good grad level audio DSP textbook?
Whats a good rigorous grad level textbook on DSP focused on audio/spectral analysis? Coming from a half proof based half applied math/physics background; have done several research projects where I worked with spectra and did audio analysis but never really understood all the details I always see in posts on this site.

Take a look at https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/sasp/

I hear (haven't read, so not posting this as an answer) good things about Richard Lyon's "Understanding Digital Signal Processing" (and I hear that from fellow radio signal processing people, not from Rick himself). Personally, coming from a communications engineering background, I like the signal theory in Lapidoth's (free!) "A foundation in digital communication", which does explain the vector space aspects of things nicely. If you need to dig deeper into what a spectrum, as a property of a random process, is, Kay's books are probably go-to, or Stoica/Moses

@Hilmar Lots of other good links from Prof. Smith: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/

There aren't very many graduate-level DSP books that are specifically about audio.  But there are important DSP books that you should have for graduate-level work in DSP, whether it's audio or some other signal class.
This would include, what we used to call "scripture", Oppenheim & Schafer.  Another old DSP book, that was the first to have sorta audio-oriented examples and student problems is Orfanidis.
There are some textbooks on DSP and speech processing, an application space that shares a lot in common with audio.  The only textbook I have (that I know of) is Rabiner & Schafer.
And, lastly, a good communications textbook can be useful for understanding frequency domain and spectral analysis of any signal class. Carlson  And, if you need undergraduate underpinnings probably Oppenheim & Willsky would be good, but I suspect that the OP might be further along than this book.  But it's a good reference along with O&S above.
These are all quite old textbooks.  There are versions of O&S that are a half-century old.  But they got the rigorous math and not all audio books have that.
Now, I do have three textbooks with the word "audio" on the cover and DSP with pretty rigorous math:

Steiglitz
Zölzer
Reiss & McPherson
There is this book that I don't have (yet): Pirkle

These are all senior or graduate-level Electrical Engineering books.  (Of course, any decent mathematician or physicist would have the math chops for these books.)
Now there are a few decently technical books, about digital music synthesis or computer music and audio, but maybe less mathy.  Like Pohlmann or Russ.
That's about all I can think of at the moment.
About your emphasis in spectral analysis, they're all about both time and frequency-domain representations of audio signals.  It's not just about one or the other.  The two domains go hand-in-hand.
Now, if this is about some really specific spectral analysis of audio or acoustic signals, like analyzing the spectra of signals and yanking parameters out of such spectra, that's so parochial that you're really in the published lit in journals about it.  I dunno.  All this depends more specifically what you're look for.

Here's a couple more interesting books I just dug up.  Elements of Computer Music and Representations of Musical Signals.

I second the recommendation of Zölzer's "Digital Audio Signal Processing". I have been in his lecture couple of years ago and the topic is well-prepared and presented in his book.

@robertbristow-johnson 'Tis a shame you don't mention B.P. Lathi's "signal processing and linear systems" for undergraduate underpinnings. In my opinion a very good signals book.

I have to confess @Carl that I had not heard of this book.  But it's clearly there.
